How to convert encoded Preeti font text to unicode leaving English words as it is in Python?
I am trying to convert Preeti font text to unicode. I am using Python and npTTF2UTF library. It works most of the time but it also converts English words like 'Microwave' into unicode equivalent. How can I avoid that?
Here is my code:
import npttf2utf

mapper = npttf2utf.FontMapper("npttf2utf-main/src/npttf2utf/map.json")

text = ''' cGo g]6js{;Fu cfj4 x"g] :yfg, tl/sf / lsl;d like (Microwave/Satellite/Cable etc.)  '''

converted_text = mapper.map_to_unicode(word, from_font="Preeti", unescape_html_input=False, escape_html_output=False)  

print(converted_text)

I get:
अन्य नेटवर्कसँग आवद्ध हूने स्थान, तरिका र किसिम ष्पिभ ९ःष्अचयधबखभरक्बतभििष्तभरऋबदभि भतअ।०
I don't want the text after 'lsl;d'(किसिम) converted into unicode. How can I do so?

I have no idea how that’s supposed to work. Your text uses ASCII letters and just maps them to Hindi characters arbitrarily. No idea how a computer is supposed to figure out that these characters are supposed to be mapped but those same letter aren’t. — Where does this text come from? I suppose in the original the sections had their own font assigned; information which got lost when copy-pasting just the text?

The text comes from PDF file which is in Nepali Language. They have text written in Nepali like: 'मेराे नाम प्रतिक हाे' (My name is Pratik). When I extract the text of the PDF using PyMuPDF i get 'd]/f] gfd k/tls xf]'

@deceze I am wildly guessing that: "Preeti" is a font that maps ASCII characters to Devanagari script glyphs, as a compatibility hack so that speakers of languages using that script (such as Nepali, as here) can type their language more easily with Western keyboards etc. The library in question is supposed to translate those characters to the proper Unicode characters that are actually supposed to map to those glyphs.

(This would be similar to conventions used decades ago, before the ubiquity of Unicode support, by Russians in order to type in a rough approximation of Cyrillic, in situations where even code pages could not be relied upon, by e.g. writing 3 instead of З (Cyrillic "ze").)

Anyway, there isn't a realistic way to answer this, because there is no rule by which a program could know that the input like should mean the English like, and not ष्पिभ (if I counted/guessed properly).

@Karl Yes, that's what I said. :) Pratik: The problem is that within the PDF, those different passages are marked up with different fonts. If you just copy-paste the text itself without the accompanying font information, that critical piece of information is lost, and there's no realistic way to do the conversation correctly. You need to extract the text together with its font information, and convert only the parts which are set to have the Preeti font.

Most legacy to Unicode conversions I have worked on was usually within the context of word documents and converters could target text in a specific font. In this case you'd need to do language detection and strip or ignore anything identified as English. The given example could be split on <space, slash, space> but that would only work if other strings followed the same pattern. With only one sample string it's hard to say if there are patterns that could be used to segment the text or not.

Thanks guys, I did as @deceze said, extracted the text together with it's font information (using PyMuPDF) and converted only parts which are set to have the Preeti font and it worked!

Extract the text together with it's font information (PyMuPDF has this feature) and convert only parts which are set to have the Preeti font.
